# In ExpressJS Generator what is the Views folder for?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack

## Background

I am building a MEAN app and have a basic angular app template built. I then went on to generate the expressjs app with

> npm install express-generator -g

**and**

> express myapp

I had read that all the server-side things should go into the `public` folder generated. I deleted everything out of the public folder that was generated and put my angular app in there.

Here is a link to my [Github Repo](https://github.com/joeLloyd/GettingMEAN) containing the app.

## MyApp

Upon putting my app into the public folder I ran the command

> DEBUG=myapp npm start

to begin running it. It worked perfectly so I began to take a closer look at the folders and files generated my Express JS.

## Views

I went through some of the folders when I saw the views folder. It contains `.jade` files, I know that jade is just a more streamlined way of writing some `.html` files but I wondered why there was a folder for html views that is outside of the public folder.

## Question

If the public folder is supposed to hold the client side app then why is there another views folder with 'html' in it? Or am I missing something here?

## Note

This is the tree that is built from the app in-case you are not aware.

```
.
├── app.js
├── bin
│   └── www
├── package.json
├── public
│   └── MyAngularApp
├── routes
│   ├── index.js
│   └── users.js
└── views
    ├── error.jade
    ├── index.jade
    └── layout.jade
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Angular, probably you want to use the server just as an API, so the `views` folder is not needed for you.

The view folder is needed when you want to return dynamic content directly from the server.

An example can be, you want to return a page containing a list of something. Then in your controller you make a query, pass the result to the view, the HTML gets compiled and returned.

If you know PHP is what you normally do in a PHP app.

But with nodejs it is easier to just make APIs and then make a client side app with angular or React (which I prefer)

Comment: Can I use the Views folder for server responses then like 404 or `Site under maintenance`? Since those kind of pages don't necessarily have to be built as part of the app.

Comment: Yes, you can use them for that.